# How to avoid duplication in __init__.py and README.md

Tags: python, github

I have a python package which has short docstrings in each `__init__.py` module, explaining what the module does etc.

The package is hosted on GitHub, and I want to make this information easily visible to users who browse the repository online. One option would then be to duplicate the whole docstring from `__init__.py` into a `README.md` file, but this violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Don't go down that path. Normally you make the documentation (including the documentation in the `__init__`) available through other means, for example sphinx and readthedocs are quite popular atm.

Comment: Sure, I agree and thats why we have it. But when browsing the repository on github it would be nice to get a short introduction to whatever subdirectory I'm currently browsing. But perhaps it is not possible?

Comment: You could add hooks that auto-generate these when you merge or publish changes. However the documentation (`__init__`) for a module is for users, the preview on github is normally aimed at the developers - that's why it's generally not customary to use the same "docs" for both.

Comment: Agree, but seeing the user doc (at  least to me) beast seeing no doc at all.